# Triggering a server action on a specific event

Tags: imap, email

I would like to launch a specific command [1] on a mail server whenever a message is moved from one folder into another folder.

For example, a Thunderbird user moves a message from folder A to Folder B. I'd like to catch this move and launch a specific script on the server.

Is it possible ?

I'm using qmail with courier-imap.

[1] bash or python script, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) were created for this:

> inotify is a Linux kernel subsystem
>   that provides file system event
>   notification.

You could use [inotify-tools](http://inotify-tools.sourceforge.net/) or [incron](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=about&lang=en) for this.
To be portable between systems that do not implement
inotify you can use [Gamin](http://www.gnome.org/~veillard/gamin/index.html) which will fallback to
supported subsystem like dnotify etc.

Comment: Thanks very much. And with inotify it will be supported on every mail server, not just qmail.

Comment: If all your users access their email via your Courier-IMAP server, then it would make sense to make a modification to that server instead of trying to watch 'outside' with inotify. (It will be simpler, and more portable.)